# How do I fix my floating menu and show it after 450px

Tags: jquery

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/EhLsT/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#header").offset().top) {
    $("#floating").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#floating").hide();
  }
});
```

I want to show my `#floating` after `450px` scrollTop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure if a understand right your question but il you wan to display `#floating` after 450px try this :

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#header").height()) {
    $("#floating").show();
  }
  else {
    $("#floating").hide();
  }
});
```

Simply change `$("#header").offset().top` to `$("#header").height()`

Comment: How do I positioning the `green bar` after `#header`?

Comment: you can add `top:0` on the `#floating` div. I have update your  jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EhLsT/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 450) {
    $("#floating").fadeIn(500);
  }
  else {
    $("#floating").hide();
  }
});​

#floating {
    height:30px;
    background:#00CC00;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    width:500px;
    top:450px;
}​
```